# Bootstrap 4 - form element not using full width

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am having a difficult time making a form appear as desired.  I would like the form to be the full width.
I've tried using form horizontal:

```
<Container fluid>
    <div className='row'>
        <form className='form-horizontal'>
            <div className='form-group row'>
              <input type='hidden' name='lId' value={entity.id} />
              <div className='col-md-4'>
                  <label className='control-label' htmlFor='PrimaryFirst'>Primary First Name</label>
                  <input className='form-control' type='text' name='PrimaryFirst' />
              </div>
              <div className='col-md-4'>
                  <label className='control-label' htmlFor='PrimaryMiddle'>Primary Middle Name</label>
                  <input className='form-control' type='text' name='PrimaryMiddle' />
              </div>
              <div className='col-md-4'>
                  <label className='control-label' htmlFor='PrimaryLast'>Primary Last Name</label>
                  <input className='form-control' type='text' name='PrimaryLast' />
              </div>
           </div>
           <div className='form-group row'>
              <div className='col-md-4'>
                  <label className='control-label' htmlFor='PrimaryHomePhone'>Primary Home Phone</label>
                  <input className='form-control' type='text' name='PrimaryHomePhone' />
              </div>
              <div className='col-md-4'>
                  <label className='control-label' htmlFor='PrimaryMobilePhone'>Primary Mobile Phone</label>
                  <input className='form-control' type='text' name='PrimaryMobilePhone' />
              </div>
              <div className='col-md-4'>
                  <label className='control-label' htmlFor='PrimaryOfficePhone'>Primary Office Phone</label>
                  <input className='form-control' type='text' name='PrimaryOfficePhone' />
              </div>
              <div className='col-md-4'>
                  <label className='control-label' htmlFor='PrimaryOtherPhone'>Primary Other Phone</label>
                  <input className='form-control' type='text' name='PrimaryOtherPhone' />
              </div>
           </div>
       </form>
 </Container>
```

Using the above renders like this:

[image]

Changing to form-vertical renders the same:

```
<form className='form-vertical'>
```

Changing to form-inline renders much different and doesn't create rows:

```
<form className='form-inline'>
```

[image]

I think form-horizontal is the class that i want but the form is not taking up the full width.
How can i make the form take up the available width and align the inputs as 3 in the first row and 4 in the second row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a total of 12 columns at maximum that you could divide so after the third `col-md-4` the 12 columns are reached and the maximum width is occupied and the fourth one goes to the nextline.What you could do is break the 12 columns into 4 pieces using `col-md-3`.

```
<Container fluid>
<div className='row'>
    <form className='form-horizontal'>
        <div className='form-group row'>
          <input type='hidden' name='lId' value={entity.id} />
          <div className='col-md-4'>
              <label className='control-label' htmlFor='PrimaryFirst'>Primary First Name</label>
              <input className='form-control' type='text' name='PrimaryFirst' />
          </div>
          <div className='col-md-4'>
              <label className='control-label' htmlFor='PrimaryMiddle'>Primary Middle Name</label>
              <input className='form-control' type='text' name='PrimaryMiddle' />
          </div>
          <div className='col-md-4'>
              <label className='control-label' htmlFor='PrimaryLast'>Primary Last Name</label>
              <input className='form-control' type='text' name='PrimaryLast' />
          </div>
       </div>
       <div className='form-group row'>
          <div className='col-md-3'>
              <label className='control-label' htmlFor='PrimaryHomePhone'>Primary Home Phone</label>
              <input className='form-control' type='text' name='PrimaryHomePhone' />
          </div>
          <div className='col-md-3'>
              <label className='control-label' htmlFor='PrimaryMobilePhone'>Primary Mobile Phone</label>
              <input className='form-control' type='text' name='PrimaryMobilePhone' />
          </div>
          <div className='col-md-3'>
              <label className='control-label' htmlFor='PrimaryOfficePhone'>Primary Office Phone</label>
              <input className='form-control' type='text' name='PrimaryOfficePhone' />
          </div>
          <div className='col-md-3'>
              <label className='control-label' htmlFor='PrimaryOtherPhone'>Primary Other Phone</label>
              <input className='form-control' type='text' name='PrimaryOtherPhone' />
          </div>
       </div>
   </form>
```